# What is the noun derived from "to compromise (a computer system)", or the correct expression for this fact?

Tags: word-request, nouns

In information security, in order to express the fact that a system was successfully attacked and taken over, one usually uses the verb *compromised*

> The system was compromised after a successful attack. It is not safe to use.

What is the noun derived from that verb? The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/compromise) does not seem to offer one - I thought that *a compromission* would exist but this is not the case.

On the other hand, *a compromise* only has the meaning of (roughly speaking) an agreement.

**Is there a good way to express "the fact of having been compromised"? (in a computer security context)**

Answer (score 3):

The noun for the attack is also **compromise**.  I think this is a relatively new usage of the word, so you may not find it in dictionaries.

Examples:

> [In one case, the contaminated control software was downloaded 250 times by unsuspecting users before the compromise was discovered.](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/congress-is-overdue-in-dealing-with-the-cybersecurity-threat/2014/07/13/2dc20bb2-0841-11e4-8a6a-19355c7e870a_story.html)

> [If you believe the compromise was caused by malicious code, disconnect your computer from the Internet.](https://www.readynh.gov/disasters/cyber.htm)

> [As the scale of the compromise of SolarWinds’ Orion platform – which is so far known to have struck multiple US government departments and cyber security firm FireEye – continues to grow...](https://www.computerweekly.com/news/252493662/SolarWinds-cyber-attack-How-worried-should-I-be-and-what-do-I-do-now)

Comment: A related term is “intrusion”. *The company’s systems had been compromised for months before the intrusion was detected.* https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/09/massive-equifax-hack-reportedly-started-4-months-before-it-was-detected/